# Фильтр четных значений в list

Tags: python, list

Задача:

> Пользователь вводит несколько чисел. Потом из них выводятся только
> чётные.

Как это сделать с применением списков, циклов и условий? Возможно ли это сделать?

Я пытался это сделать, но безуспешно.
В ходе попыток найти решение, я выяснил как извлечь из известного списка чётные элементы через `for`

Пример:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
b = []
for i in a:
    if i % 2 == 0:
        b.append(i)
    print (b)
```

Здесь выводятся уже из известного списка, заданного автором кода.
Также я выяснил как преобразовать тип (или класс) «string», получаемый от пользователя через «input», в тип «list».

Пример.
a = list(input('Введи числа'))

Но здесь есть одна из проблем, как я думаю. В этом случае введенные данные пользователем в список, но элементы списка получаются как строки, а не цифры. Выглядит это как-то так:
`['1', '2']`. А не `[1, 2]`
Как это исправить я не нашёл. Находил про команду `«map»`, но про неё непонятно было написано и сколько не пробовал, выдавало ошибку.

Вот один из вариантов, который я пробовал:

```
a = list(input('Введи числа'))
b = []
for i in a:
   if i % 2 == 0:
      b.append()
print (b)
```

Были и другие способы, но я решил их здесь не писать.

Поэтому прошу, объяснить как можно решить данную задачу. Желательно подробно с полным кодом, а не «там вставь, там допиши». Я новичок и могу не понять такой ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
numbers_string = input("Введите числа: ") # создание строки с числами через пробел

# split() возвращает список
# дальше выбираете на свой вкус какой вариант вам по душе
string_to_list = [int(number) for number in numbers_string.split(' ')] # с применением генератора
string_to_list = []
for number in numbers_string.split(' '): # с применением цикла
    string_to_list.append(int(number))

even = [number for number in string_to_list if number % 2 == 0] # с применением генератора
even = []
for number in string_to_list: # с применением цикла
    if number % 2 == 0:
        even.append(number)

print(string_to_list, even)
```

Comment: Благодарю за помощь.